# Firewalk through a Firewall on our subnet

Tags: firewalls, ports, nmap

Having trouble firewalking. I am trying to determine all the open ports on my firewall/gateway. Here is my lab network diagram:

[image: Network Diagram]

(Skip to the bottom of the following explanation for a direct list of my questions)

**Configuration Details:**

- Firewall is an ASA 5505 with static routes.
- The firewall will respond to ICMP echo requests at 192.168.1.2.
- The firewall has TCP port 31337 left intentionally open so that we can detect it as part of the exercise.
- The "Host" at 192.168.1.4 is acting as the "attacker" trying to determine the open ports.
- The "Attacker" is running Kali linux.
- The "Target" host is running Windows Web Server 2008 (not sure that matters).

**Attempted Methods:**

I have tried both the ["Firewalk"](http://packetfactory.openwall.net/projects/firewalk/index.html) tool by Packetfactory and also the [Nmap firewalk script](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/firewalk.html). Here are examples of the syntax I am using:

**Nmap:** `nmap --traceroute --script=firewalk --script-args=firewalk.max-probed-ports=-1 192.168.3.11`

**CORRECT SYNTAX FOR NMAP:** (solved this!) `nmap --traceroute --script=firewalk 192.168.3.11 -p1-65535`

- NMAP only scans common ports by default. The full port range must be specified.

I simply needed to add the nmap port scan switches in as those are not arguments that can be passed into the firewalk script. I'm still learning...

**Firewalk:** `firewalk 192.168.1.2 192.168.3.11`

Current Results of firewalking methods:

**Nmap** (This list is incomplete *but shouldn't be* - port 31337 has been opened intentionally on this firewall)

```
 Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-03-17 11:15 EDT
 Nmap scan report for 192.168.3.11
 Host is up (0.0026s latency).
 Not shown: 987 closed ports
 PORT      STATE    SERVICE
 80/tcp    open     http
 111/tcp   filtered rpcbind
 135/tcp   filtered msrpc
 139/tcp   filtered netbios-ssn
 445/tcp   filtered microsoft-ds
 1720/tcp  filtered H.323/Q.931
 2000/tcp  filtered cisco-sccp
 5060/tcp  filtered sip
 49152/tcp filtered unknown
 49153/tcp filtered unknown
 49154/tcp filtered unknown
 49155/tcp filtered unknown
 49156/tcp filtered unknown

 Host script results:
 | firewalk: 
 | HOP  HOST          PROTOCOL  BLOCKED PORTS
 |_0    192.168.1.43  tcp       111,135,139,445,1720,2000,5060,49152-49156

 TRACEROUTE (using port 1025/tcp)
 HOP RTT     ADDRESS
 1   3.19 ms 192.168.3.11
```

**Firewalk**

```
 Firewalk 5.0 [gateway ACL scanner]
 Firewalk state initialization completed successfully. UDP-based scan.
 Ramping phase source port: 53, destination port: 33434
 Hotfoot through 192.168.1.2 using 192.168.3.11 as a metric.
 Ramping Phase:
 1 (TTL  1): *no response*
 2 (TTL  2): *no response*
 ...
 25 (TTL 25): *no response*
 Scan aborted: hopcount exceeded.
```

**Questions:**

- Why doesn't the "Firewalk" tool ever see the target gateway (firewall at 192.168.1.2)? Nmap appears to be able to.
- Why doesn't the Nmap firewalk script show me all the open ports?
- How do I configure the Nmap firewalk script arguments to ONLY check the firewall for port 31337 TCP? (*figured this out!* `-p31337` or `-p1-65535`. Duh - see the corrected syntax above)

P.S. also thanks to ["Gliffy"](https://www.gliffy.com) for the awesome online network diagramming tool :)

Comment: Can you try specifying more flags for firewalk(1)? e.g., `firewalk -n -pTCP -S25,53,80,443,465,587,5353 192.168.1.2 192.168.3.11'. Maybe it's a name resolution or ICMP/UDP issue?

Comment: Hmmm seems like it fails during ramping phase and the other flags don't matter... Any switches that I can change that would bypass the ramping phase?

Comment: Perhaps it would be `firewalk -d 80 -n -pTCP 192.168.1.2 192.168.3.11''? See the man page -- http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=firewalk&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+Ports+10.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html

Comment: @atdre Different error now! But that seems like progress... `metric responded before target; must not be en route`

Comment: Great detailed question!

Comment: @PaulD Thank you! I find that I always get the best responses when I am thorough but well organized... :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=firewalk&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%20Ports%2010.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), firewalk looks to need the following flags in order to properly scan when you are one hop from your gateway (as seen in your pretty Gliffy picture).

> firewalk -d 49152 -r 192.168.1.2 192.168.3.11

Comment: Thanks but no dice for me! I am still getting no response in the ramping phase. The ramping phase fails and then firewalk aborts.

Comment: @ Shrout1: Did you try putting them both together like the above?

Comment: Yep! Did a copy paste and my ramping phase still fails

Comment: Try the -t, -T, and -x flags with values that make sense to your environment as well

Comment: Hey! Tried -t, -x and -T but it still seems like the ramping phase fails.

Comment: Try using `strace -fx firewalk <flags> <ip> <ip>' and see what's stopping it. Or use tcpdump (or Wireshark) and compare the firewalkk traffic from the original tool to the nmap NSE scripts.